# ext2/ext3 in embedded device

Tags: embedded, ext3, ext2

I would like to be able to use the ext2 or ext3 file system in an embedded device without having to use Linux. I plan to have an embedded processor with a SATA hard drive attached. I have found the source code on Kernel.org but I am unsure how to use it. Idealy I would like to have some functions I can call to write/read a file etc. Is there any documentation about this or has anyone done something similar.

Thanks

Jon

Comment: The code at Kernel.org is Linux specific so is unlikely to port directly.  When deploying a file system on an embedded system you will have to provide your own block device driver too.  I have only ever deployed FAT32 on a bare-metal or RTOS base system.  If what you are after is a journalling file system then Segger emFile has a journalling add-on for its FAT based file system: http://www.segger.com/emfile_journaling.html - not for free though!

Comment: I have a FAT32 system up and running but I am using it with a 500GB hard disk. I am finding that some operations, like free space calculations, are taking a long time. So I am lookig for an alternative.

Comment: I doubt it would be that much work to port - you'd obviously need a block-level layer to sit below it and a filing system abstraction layer to sit above. Besides that, you'd to provide equivalents of various other things such as memory management. 

It might be worth having a look at Barebox (http://barebox.org/) where one of the design intents has been to allow easy porting of linux drivers.  Not sure if anybody has got Ext2/3 working on there yet, but they certainly have a lot of the infrastructure there for it.